# Is it possible to use interpolation in value binding in angular

Tags: angular, interpolation

I would like to bind the field i want to use for the value field dynamically

I want to do something like this

```
<option [value]="item.{{fieldName}}">{{item._id}}</option>
```

Field name will be read from a config file. Can i do this kind of thing in angular ?

Comment: Why don't you do simply: `getItem(fieldName)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using square bracket notation

```
[value]="item[fieldName]"
```